# How to unmerge same-key array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I unmerge same-key elements into separate elements?

```
array (size=1)
  'City' => 
    array
      'S' => 
        array 
          'Red' => 
            array 
              'SKU-1' => string 'Description 1'
          'Red' => 
            array 
              'SKU-2' => string 'Description 2'
```

Desired output:

```
array (size=2)
  'City' => 
    array
      'S' => 
        array 
          'Red' => 
            array 
              'SKU-1' => string 'Description 1'
  'City' => 
    array
      'S' => 
        array 
          'Red' => 
            array 
              'SKU-2' => string 'Description 2'
```

So, instead of just having 1 element, the array has 2 elements even though the keys are the same.

Comment: Arrays in PHP always have unique keys. It's not possible for 2 elements to have the exact same key. Ever. Just think about it: how would you reference the element?? $array['Red']  would be... what? the first? or the 2nd element? Or am I misunderstanding your question ?

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I asked this is because when iterating the array, I need to get a unique combination iteration counting number (int) for each SKU (i.e 0000 or 0111 representing $city.$size.$color.$sku) even though the key-names are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have duplicated keys, they will always overwrite.
You can do it like this.

```
array (size=2)
  'City' => 
    array=>
         0 => array
            'S' => 
                array 
                'Red' => 
                 array 
                   'SKU-1' => string 'Description 1'
         1 => array
           'S' => 
              array 
               'Red' => 
                  array 
                   'SKU-2' => string 'Description 2'
```

Comment: Thank you. But how I can convert that key-name/value pair multi-dimensional array elements into index-based elements?